# Ruby Hash and Tumblr API

Tags: ruby, api, tumblr

[controller page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VVao.png), [Json output from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81mrd.png)

I'm trying to display posts from the users tumblr account on my view page using ruby. I have never done anything with api's before. I'm trying to use Hash tables. my controller code is as such:

```
@Posts = client.posts"zombieprocess1.tumblr.com"
```

on my view page using html I have

```
<%=Posts%>
```

the response is such

```
{"blog"=>{"title"=>"Untitled", "name"=>"zombieprocess1", "total_posts"=>1, "posts"=>1, "url"=>"URL", "updated"=>1478191052, "description"=>"", "is_nsfw"=>false, "ask"=>false, "ask_page_title"=>"Ask me anything", "ask_anon"=>false, "followed"=>false, "can_send_fan_mail"=>true, "is_blocked_from_primary"=>false, "share_likes"=>true, "likes"=>1, "twitter_enabled"=>false, "twitter_send"=>false, "facebook_opengraph_enabled"=>"N", "tweet"=>"N", "facebook"=>"N", "followers"=>0, "primary"=>true, "admin"=>true, "messages"=>0, "queue"=>0, "drafts"=>0, "type"=>"public", "reply_conditions"=>3, "subscribed"=>false, "can_subscribe"=>false}, "posts"=>[{"blog_name"=>"zombieprocess1", "id"=>152689921093, "post_url"=>"URL", "slug"=>"", "type"=>"photo", "date"=>"2016-11-03 16:37:32 GMT", "timestamp"=>1478191052, "state"=>"published", "format"=>"html", "reblog_key"=>"NCDqGTzW", "tags"=>[], "short_url"=>"URL", "summary"=>"", "recommended_source"=>nil, "recommended_color"=>nil, "followed"=>false, "liked"=>true, "note_count"=>1, "caption"=>"", "reblog"=>{"tree_html"=>"", "comment"=>""}, "trail"=>[], "image_permalink"=>"url", "photos"=>[{"caption"=>"", "alt_sizes"=>[{"url"=>"URL", "width"=>400, "height"=>544}, {"url"=>"URL", "width"=>250, "height"=>340}, {"url"=>"URL", "width"=>100, "height"=>136}, {"url"=>"URL", "width"=>75, "height"=>75}], "original_size"=>{"url"=>"URL", "width"=>400, "height"=>544}}], "can_like"=>false, "can_reblog"=>true, "can_send_in_message"=>true, "can_reply"=>true, "display_avatar"=>true}], "total_posts"=>1}
```

I have tried many different formats and can't seem to just get the post url. My thought is to get the post_url and embed each of them so it shows as it would in tumblr on my webpage. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@posts['posts'].first['post_url']
```

Or if your response contains more than one post you can return them all like this:

```
(0...@posts['total_posts']).map { |i| @posts['posts'][i]['post_url'] }
```

EDIT: Fixed capitalization in second line of code. I assume you are using lowercase variable as per Ruby convention, '@posts'. If not, you should change to a lowercase variable as this may be confusing something.

Comment: I tried both. the first one return no errors but does not post anything to my page and I am using '<%=blah%> and the second one returned an error 'bad value for range'

Comment: Have you assigned the hash to a variable in the console and played around with it? The code I gave you does return the post_url. You may have another issue in your view or controller.

Comment: I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Ive googled everything I know to google. I am very new at ruby as well. I used the second bit of coding and corrected my variables. I set it equal to @post_url in my controller and went to print the urls to my view page and still nothing.

Comment: I added images of my controller and the json output from the api. the controller image is from before I changed my variables to lowercase.

Comment: Also i am using the tumblr_client gem. Im not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure either, and I don't know what's going on behind the scenes. But what is the purpose of the three lines immediately before the `@posts_url` assignment? It seems an attempt to morph `@posts` in place, which sometimes has unexpected results. Try removing those three lines and see if it changes anything.